# Call to a member function store() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy haciendo un formulario que envia un logo de empresa a almacenar pero recibo el error `Call to a member function store() on null` que segun entiendo es porque el campo se encuentra vacio, revise mi consola y en la url note que el archivo si se envia pero con este formato `empresa_logo=%5Bobject%20File%5D` ya intente mil formas y no almacena la fotografia espero puedan ayudarme, PD: los demas campos si los almacena solo falta el archivo.

La ruta esta configurada de la siguiente forma: `Route::get('empresas', 'EmpresasController@store')->name('empresas.store');`

Este es mi controlador en el metodo Store:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $empresa = new Empresa([
            'nombreempresa' => $request->get('nombreempresa'),
            'nombrecomercial' => $request->get('nombrecomercial'),
            'idfiscal' => $request->get('idfiscal'),
            'adminid' => auth()->id(),
            'tel' => $request->get('tel'),
            'calleynumero' => $request->get('calleynumero'),
            'colonia' => $request->get('colonia'),
            'ciudad' => $request->get('ciudad'),
            'estado' => $request->get('estado'),
            'codigopostal' => $request->get('codigopostal'),
            'pais' => $request->get('pais'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'acceso' => '1',
            'sector' => $request->get('sector'),
            'tipo' => $request->get('tipo'),
            'sitioweb' => $request->get('sitioweb'),
            'empresa_logo' => $request->file('empresa_logo')->store('empresas-logo', 'public'),
            'serial' => 'XEVB-TBMN-KHKL-YB2JI89J',
            'wizard' => '1'
        ]);
        $empresa->save();
        $relacionempresa = new Empleado([
            'nombres' => auth()->user()->FirstName,
            'ApellidoPaterno' => auth()->user()->LastName,
            'ApellidoMaterno' => auth()->user()->LastName2,
            'is_verified' => '0',
            'puesto' => $request->get('puesto'),
            'email' => auth()->user()->email,
            'empresa_id' => $empresa->id,
            'empresa_name' => $empresa->nombrecomercial,
            'empresa_logo' => $empresa->empresa_logo,
            'sector' => $empresa->sector
        ]);
        $relacionempresa->save();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('success', 'Gracias hemos recibido tu informacion!');
    }
```

Este es el modelo:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Empleado extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'empleados';

    /**
    * The database primary key value.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $hidden = [
     'api_token'
    ];
    /**
     * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'nombres',
    'ApellidoPaterno',
    'ApellidoMaterno',
    'is_verified',
    'email',
    'bio',
    'puesto',
    'ubicacion',
    'status',
    'picture',
    'sector',
    'empresa_id',
    'empresa_name',
    'created_at',
    'empresa_logo',
    'updated_at'];
}
```

y por ultimo este es mi formulario en blade:

```
<form method="PUT" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('empresas.store') }}" id="kt_form" class="kt-form kt-form--fit kt-form--label-right" >
                                            @csrf
                                            <!--begin: Form Wizard Step 1-->
                                            <div class="kt-wizard-v2__content" data-ktwizard-type="step-content" data-ktwizard-state="current">
                                                <div class="kt-heading kt-heading--md">{{ __('forms.Account_Details') }}</div>
                                                <div class="kt-form__section kt-form__section--first">
                                                    <div class="kt-wizard-v2__form">
                                                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                                                <label class="">{{ __('forms.Nombre_Comercial') }}</label>
                                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="empresa_logo" id="empresa_logo">
                                                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="empresa_logo"></label>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('forms.Indication_NC') }}</span>
                                                            </div>

                                            <!--end: Form Actions -->
                                        </form>
```

Comment: Por convención, toda solicitud HTTP que vaya a guardar informacion en la base de datos, se envía en POST, no en GET.

Comment: Me parece que la etiqueta `form` solo soporta la declaración de `POST` o `GET` en el atributo `method`; en todo caso pudieras cambiar eso y con una de las directivas de blade hacer lo siguiente: `@method('PUT')`